# Compare a sort list item with a string for a UItableview title

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, sorting, compare

I sorted a list in a table view, but i don't want to show the item of the list as the title of the row. I need to compare the first item of the sorted list with a string, and if it is the same, I want to show an other string as the title.

Just as an example, to explain it better:

```
if (first item of the sorted list == some string) {

   cell.textlabel.text = @"name";

}
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Is your sorted array stored in an `NSArray`? If so, you can use:

```
if ([[sortedArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Some String"]) {
    cell.textlabel.text = @"name";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have interpreted the question correctly, then yes it is. If the first item was a cell, which it would be presumably, then you could do;

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *firstCell = [yourTableView cellForRowAtIndePath:indexPath];
NSString *titleOfFirstCell = firstCell.textLabel.text;
```

Then you could compare it to check what it should be changed to - I'm going to call this string 'updatedTitle'.

```
titleOfFirstCell.textLabel.text = updatedTitle;
[firstCell setNeedsDisplay];
```

Hope this helps,

Jonathan